# Right Click on Button with ContextMenu disabled makes button look stuck

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is there a way to avoid this? This happens with Chrome on Windows. You can see what I mean if you run the snippet.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

```html
<button id='btn'>Right Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="test">Test</button>

document.getElementById("test").onmousedown = function(event) {
    if (event.which == 3) {
        alert("right clicked!");
    }
}
```

link : http://jsfiddle.net/Jmmqz/

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I'm asking. I'm talking about the button getting stuck when right clicked and context menu is disabled.